# how to merge two dataframes in r with NAs present in common column in it in r

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I have a master dataset looks like

```
A1       B1         V1
1100    10129       45
NA      1012        65
NA      101         47
NA      10132       36
1101    10133       425
36475   NA          74
54757   NA          85
1102    10136       NA
```

Here the secondary table where I need to update V2 column from V1 using two primary ids (A1 and B1)

```
A2        B2    V2
1100     10129  
NA       1012   
NA       10132  
36475    NA 
54757    NA 
1102     10136
```

Excpected output:

```
    A2       B2     V2
   1100     10129   45
   NA       1012    65
   NA       10132   36
   36475    NA      74
   54757    NA      85
   1102     10136   NA
```

kindly suggest the code to met the criteria

Thanks in advance

Comment: In base R : `merge(df1, df2, by.x = c('A1', 'B1'), by.y = c('A2', 'B2'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to do an `inner_join` would be suffice.

```
library(dplyr)

primary_df <- data.frame(
  A1 = c(1100, NA, NA, NA, 1101, 36475, 54757, 1102),
  B1= c(10129, 1012, 101, 10132, 10133, NA, NA, 10136),
  V1 = c(45, 65, 47, 36, 425, 74, 85, NA)
)

secondary_df <- data.frame(
  A2 = c(1100, NA, NA, 36475, 54757, 1102),
  B2 = c(10129, 1012, 10132, NA, NA, 10136)
)

inner_join(primary_df, secondary_df, by=c("A1"="A2", "B1"="B2"))
```

Output

```
> inner_join(primary_df, secondary_df, by=c("A1"="A2", "B1"="B2"))
     A1    B1 V1
1  1100 10129 45
2    NA  1012 65
3    NA 10132 36
4 36475    NA 74
5 54757    NA 85
6  1102 10136 NA
```